# How to enable extended application authenticity protection in Eclipse mobilefirst project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an IBM mobile first version 7.0 project which developed in Eclipse Luna. Just want to check how to enable the extended application authenticity protection for apk and ipa as mentioned in https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/#enablingExtendedApplicationAuthenticityProtection?

Thanks

Comment: Did you first try basic app authenticity ?

Comment: Application Authenticity Protection is not available in the MobileFirst Development Server. To test, deploy the application to a MobileFirst Server instance on a remote application server.

Comment: Hi, manjunath, may i know how do i turn om basic app authenticity in eclipse mobilefirst?

Comment: Follow the link you have posted it has everything ,enabling app authenticity require a MobileFirst server instance on a remote application server not the server run using eclipse .Let me know if you face any problem flowing the link .

Answer (score 0):

Application authenticity protection is only available in standalone ( production) installs of IBM MobileFirst server. Application authenticity feature is disabled in IBM MFP Studio.

Once you have installed your standalone server, make use of the 'wladm' command to enable extended application authenticity protection.